# Share htaccess config between multiple apache servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm running multiple apache servers for load balancing purposes. Each has an htaccess file which are identical.

The htaccess file is often updated several times per week which can become challenging to ensure all stay in sync.

Is there a way to share the configuration from 1 location to reduce the number of files to keep in sync?